# t.substring is not a function in ApexCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, apexcharts

Porridge everyone, I got a bug in ApexCharts. Who knows what this is wrong? Thanks!

**My Code**:

```
// Option Chart
var options = {
          series: 
          [ 
            {
              name: 'Operating',
              data: [1785, 1661, 1663, 1653, 1882, 1725, 6153, 1153, 6153, 6153, 6153, 1653, 1153, 1663, 1661]
            }, {
              name: 'Stopping',
              data: [4072, 0, 0, 0, 248, 2534, 8533, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            }, {
              name: 'Error',
              data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            },{
              name: 'No Sign',
              data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            }
          ],  
          chart: {
          type: 'bar',
          height: heightChart,
          stacked: true,
          stackType: '100%'
          },
          responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 480,
            options: {
              legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                offsetX: -10,
                offsetY: 0
              }
            }
          }],
          xaxis: {
            labels: {
              style: {
                colors: [],
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 400,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
              }
            },
          },
          yaxis: {
            labels: {
              style: {
                colors: [],
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 400,
                cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
              }
            },
          },
      };
      var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
      chart.render();
```

**This Is Error**:

[image]

I tried to find out about this error, mostly due to data errors. But my data is right. When we replace 0 to 1 this error disappears.
And after creating the plot option, the graph generated an error:

```
plotOptions: {
            bar: {
              columnWidth: '60%',
              colors: {
                ranges: [{
                    from: 0,
                    to: 0,
                    color: ['#0000']
                }],
                backgroundBarColors: [],
                backgroundBarOpacity: 1,
                backgroundBarRadius: 0,
              },
            }
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs fine (produces the result as shown below) and generates no errors on my side.

Can you check which version of ApexCharts are you using?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!
I am using:
  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts.
And I'm missing:
                    plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                  columnWidth: '60%',
                  colors: {
                    ranges: [{
                        from: 0,
                        to: 0,
                        color: ['#0000']
                    }],
                    backgroundBarColors: [],
                    backgroundBarOpacity: 1,
                    backgroundBarRadius: 0,
                  },
                }
              },

Comment: You don't need to set a color range for 0 values as they are never rendered in a bar chart. And even if you want to - use this ranges: [{ from: 0, to: 0, color: '#000000' }]